# Spring CLI not found 'test' command

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cli

I have installed spring-2.2.4.RELEASE on Windows 10 but when I try to execute test via "spring test", command line shows "'test' is not a valid command. See 'help'." and I type help command the followings are what I saw:

Available commands are:

```
  run [options] <files> [--] [args]
    Run a spring groovy script

  grab
    Download a spring groovy script's dependencies to ./repository

  jar [options] <jar-name> <files>
    Create a self-contained executable jar file from a Spring Groovy script

  war [options] <war-name> <files>
    Create a self-contained executable war file from a Spring Groovy script

  install [options] <coordinates>
    Install dependencies to the lib/ext directory

  uninstall [options] <coordinates>
    Uninstall dependencies from the lib/ext directory

  init [options] [location]
    Initialize a new project using Spring Initializr (start.spring.io)

  encodepassword [options] <password to encode>
    Encode a password for use with Spring Security

  shell
    Start a nested shell
```

Yes, there is no test command but I google every spring cli test tutorial they all apply 'test' command for cli groovy test. So questions are:

1. Windows version of Spring CLI doesn't support 'test'command?
2. Do I miss some installations?
3. Or 2.2.4 version just support another way to execute test not by 'test' command
   Furthermore, if I execute run command it also run test groovy script, is there anyway to exclude test once startup applications?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for testing in the CLI (the `test` command) was [removed in Spring Boot 2.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#removed-features). The [recommendation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9087#issue-226201784) is that “once an app gets to the stage of requiring a test suite, it should be converted to a Maven or Gradle project”.